# how to rewrite language parameter in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to rewrite language parameter in htaccess?
I want to set the second part of my url as my site language,
I write the htaccess code bellow but when I print $_GET, found no $_GET['language']
why?
by the way , how to juddge using "?" or "&" in htaccess . I wrote 2 RewriteCond bellow , is there other simpple way?

```
http://www.hello.com/en/test.html
or http://www.hello.com/test.html   //default language = en
=> 
http://www.hello.com/test.html?language=en

http://www.hello.com/fr/test.html
=> 
http://www.hello.com/test.html?language=fr

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\w{2}/.*\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) $2&language=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\w{2}/[^\?]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) $2?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two strings is the simplest way since you're either capturing parameters or writing non-existent ones. When it comes to `mod_rewrite` simple isn't always the best method. This should work with `QSA`. As long as you're declaring a new query string QSA should pass the parameters automatically:

```
#Check for files that do not contain the language string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?language=en [QSA,L]

#Capture the language string and present it as the variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]{2})/(.*)
RewriteRule ^.* %2?language=%1 [QSA,L]
```